# alsamixer amixer to python dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

alsamixer store its data in a file with following syntax:

```
control.2 = {
    iface : MIXER
    name : 'DSP1 Rate'
    value:'16kHz'
    comment = {
        access 'read write'
        type ENUMERATED
        count 1
        item.0 'SYNCCLK rate'
        item.1 '8kHz'
        item.2 '16kHz'
        item.3 'ASYNCCLK rate'
    }
```

Is there a speed way to convert it to a python dictionary?
To allow reading of it from a python script ?

I've tried **pyalsaaudio** with `alsaaudio.mixers()` is possible to see the names of the controls, but with the alsa file, you can see also the availables data that you can set for that control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spend my whole afternoon doing this. Hope it'd solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import re
import json


def jsonify(config='/var/lib/alsa/asound.state'):
    g = re.MULTILINE
    p1 = re.compile(r'((?:^|"[^"]+"|\'[^\']+\'|[\s:{}])+)([^\s{}]+)', g)
    p2 = re.compile(r'^(\s*\"[\w.]+"(?!\s*[\:]))', g)
    p3 = re.compile(r'([\"\}])\n(?!\s*\})', g)

    with open(config) as fh:
        context = fh.read()
        # replace all the quote with quotes
        context = context.replace("'", '"')
        # surround the name:value objects by quotes
        context = re.sub(p1, r'\g<1>"\g<2>"', context)
        # add a trailing comma after the values assignment
        context = re.sub(p2, r'\g<1>:', context)
        # add a colon before the values as a delimiter
        context = re.sub(p3, r'\g<1>,\n', context)

    return json.loads('{\n%s\n}' % context[:-2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'you should use it as module :D'
```